# Is there a way that i can fix my server greeting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

While creating the server greeting for my discord bot and following along with a youtube video i created this part of code for my bot.

I save and run the code and it does not replace ${member} with the username of the joining member to welcome them into the server.

I've tried changing ${member} to the following:

${Member} 
and
@{member}

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

      const channel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");
      if(!channel) return;

      channel.send('Welcome to our server, ${member}, Read our server rules / introduce yourself and get comfortable! We thank you for joining our server.')
```

I Expected : Welcome to our server, @JohnDoe, Read our server rules / introduce yourself and get comfortable! We thank you for joining our server.

Actual Output : Welcome to our server, ${member}, Read our server rules / introduce yourself and get comfortable! We thank you for joining our server.

Comment: use ` instead of ' like this:\`Welcome to our server, ${member}, Read our server rules / introduce yourself and get comfortable! We thank you for joining our server.\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use back-ticks/grave accents (`` ` ``) instead of quotes, like this:

```js
`Welcome to our server, ${member}, Read our server rules / introduce yourself and get comfortable! We thank you for joining our server.`
```

<sub>[More about template literals.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)</sub>